# Fortran fibonacci woes

Tags: fortran

I am working my way through "Modern Fortran explained" by Metcalf, Reid, and Cohen and in chapter four it assigns a Fibonacci program as a homework problem.  My code below doesn't compile.  How can I correct it?

```
    !  Fibonacci here we go
    integer :: lim, i
    lim=0
    read *, lim

    integer, dimension(lim) :: fib

    if( lim >= 1 )
        fib(1) = 0
    end if

    if( lim >= 2 )
        fib(2) = 1
    end if

    if( lim >= 3 )
        fib(3) = 1
    end if

    do i=4, lim
        fib(i) = fib(i-2) + fib(i-1)
    end do

    do i=1, size(fib)
        print *, fib(i)
    end do

    end
```

Also, here are the errors I am getting.  I would attempt to shorten this to what is needed but I am not sure what one needs when looking at Fortran error logs.

```
Compiling the source code....
$/usr/bin/gfortran /tmp/135997827718658.f95 -o /tmp/135997827718658 2>&1
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:7

integer, dimension(lim) :: fib
1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:9

if( lim >= 1 )
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement in IF-clause at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:10

fib(1) = 0
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:11

end if
1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:13

if( lim >= 2 )
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement in IF-clause at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:14

fib(2) = 1
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:15

end if
1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:17

if( lim >= 3 )
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement in IF-clause at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:18

fib(3) = 1
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:19

end if
1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
In file /tmp/135997827718658.f95:22

fib(i) = fib(i-2) + fib(i-1)
1
Error: Statement function at (1) is recursive
Error: Unexpected end of file in '/tmp/135997827718658.f95'
```

Comment: If you are accustomed to Linux, I'm sure there is a gfortran or fort77 in CygWin. That presumaby hurts less. Go look for a FORTRAN tutorial on the 'net (there have been _massive_ changes in the language since FORTRAN 77, so I can't even tell if the above is correct syntax :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

random fixes....

if block should be

```
if (condition) then
  do something
endif
```

cannot ommit "then".

you cannot go

```
read *, lim
integer, dimension(lim) :: fib
```

all the declaration has to come before executable codes.   so instead, use allocatable array

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: fib
read *, lim
allocate(fib(lim))
```

Comment: I didnt know about that...  Is it good thing to know?  ending something without starting it doesn't make too much sense to me...

Comment: got rid about fuss about program statement... if compiler dont care i shouldn't have cared.   Thanks for pointint this out.